# Error in building Qt for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, qt5, nmake

I'm getting this error when try to build Qt for VS2010.

> Running syncqt...
>
> srcbase = F:/Qt/qtbase
>   outbase = F:/Qt/qtbase
>
> Creating qmake...
>
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01 
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Running configuration tests...
>   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
>   \VC\BIN\link.EXE"' : return code '0x463'
>   Stop.
>   Could not find output file: No such file or directory

I tried with arguments "configure -opengl desktop"

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you run this from a Visual Studio 2010 command prompt?

Comment: Did you install python and perl? I believe Qt5 required both the last time I built it. I used ActiveState versions for both.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes. I have installed both of them.

Comment: Did you find out what was the problem? I'm facing the same error but I can't google any solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm debugging this error, and the "Could not find output file" is about arch.exe in qtbase/config.tests/arch. So this is a consequence of the link error that happens before that.

Going in that directory and typing nmake gives me

```
link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFEST DEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:arch.exe @C:\Users\DAVIDF~1\AppData\Local\Temp\nm2E51.tmp
LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'
```

Bingo. As found in [Visual Studio can't build due to rc.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372706/visual-studio-cant-build-due-to-rc-exe), this happens when the PATH is messed up and doesn't contain the right msvc directories (in my case it was because I was prepending something to the PATH with a ':' instead of a ';'... Unix habits)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that updating VS2010 with SP1 solve this problem.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691