# Visual Studio 2010 Compile Error "xcopy exited with code -1073741515"

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a project that compiles in another machine but gives me an error like this in mine:

Error   9   The command "xcopy /s /y "C:\MV-Code\Release_1.1.9\MV.ActionLibrary\MV.ActionLibrary.TransferUpload\bin\debug*.dll"  "C:\MV-Code\Release_1.1.9\MV.ActionLibrary\MV.ActionOutputLibrary\transfer_uploaded_image\"" exited with code -1073741515.

When I run the xcopy command in CL, it runs perfectly. What am I missing here?

Win 7 64 bit, VS 2010 SP1

**Update 1:**
Path environment variable:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Media\Tools\Apps\ImageMagick;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.7.4-Q16;C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.1-Q8;C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.1-Q16;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Tail4win;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\
```

**Update 2:**
We tried creating a batch file of all the xcopy post build events and called that batch file from VS2010 and it did not work either. The problem seems to be that no post build event can be done from my installation of VS2010.

Comment: That's STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND.  Definitely not the kind of error you'd expected XCopy.exe to return, that machine is probably pretty messed up.

Comment: This is not one of the usual `xcopy` errors.  Is VS providing any more information in the Output tab?  Does the file get copied to the destination directory?  Is the "another machine" a 64 bit machine or 32 bit?  VS could be looking in the wrong place for `xcopy`, so is the `Path` environment variable pointing to the right place and is not being truncated due to excessive length?

Comment: This looks potentially related: http://i-am-bryan.com/webs/tutorials/fix-cl-exe-exited-with-code-1073741515-cannot-run-rc-exe/

Comment: @MontyWild Output TAB lists this as extra -  "error MSB3073". (I actually have 7 xcopy errors and one attrib error with the same error code.) The files do not get copied to the destination directory. The other machine is also an x64. My path statement is 1249 chars long.

Comment: @Stabledog I tried that. Funny that I did not find this folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86) on my machine. However, a tip from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372706/visual-studio-cant-build-due-to-rc-exe told me where to look. I used that location for the rest of the procedure but it did not solve the problem...

Comment: Your PATH includes three different releases of SQL Server. It might pay off to consolidate your installation and reduce it to the essential tools.

Comment: @AxelKemper Thanks for catching that one. Removed all.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I solved the same error code by adding installed features of Visual Studio, like the SDK.