# Error while executing cmake

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, dlib

I'm trying to install dlib library for python 3.5.

```
    -- The C compiler identification is unknown

    -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
    CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
      No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.


    -- Configuration incomplete, error occured!
```

The contents of CMakeError.log after trying to execute cmake in dlib:

```
Build started 13-Apr-17 7:55:06 PM.
Project "C:\Users\AnkitaShinde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\dlib\CMakeFiles\3.7.1\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
C:\Users\AnkitaShinde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\dlib\CMakeFiles\3.7.1\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj(18,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
Done Building Project "C:\Users\AnkitaShinde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\dlib\CMakeFiles\3.7.1\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\AnkitaShinde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\dlib\CMakeFiles\3.7.1\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
  C:\Users\AnkitaShinde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\dlib\CMakeFiles\3.7.1\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj(18,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.02
```

Comment: 1. Please copy & pate the text into your question instead of providing a screenshot of pure text. 2. Do you have a C compiler installed and in the `PATH` of the cmd session you're using?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. 
I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Is the problem dlib-specific? IOW, if you try generating a minimal CMake project, does that work? And can you please [edit] the question to put the text in it *as text?*

Comment: It is a dlib specific problem

Comment: `It is a dlib specific problem` - So, does simple CMake project work on your machine? Otherwise, error is not dlib- and python-specific. There are [many other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcmake%5DThe+C+compiler+identification+is+unknown) with the **same error message**, and your question doesn't contain any additional info compared to those questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (project): No CMAKE\_C\_COMPILER could be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801638/cmake-error-at-cmakelists-txt30-project-no-cmake-c-compiler-could-be-found) or [Why does MSBuild look in C:\ for Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props instead of c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild? ( error MSB4019)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092169/why-does-msbuild-look-in-c-for-microsoft-cpp-default-props-instead-of-c-progr)

Comment: Pleeeeasee fix the formatting of this questions. This is unreadable right now.

Comment: This is well known problem of MSVC compiler and not a dlib problem. By default, Visual Studio is not installing C++ compiler. Check this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31619296/cmake-does-not-find-visual-c-compiler