# cmake: no cmake_c_compiler could be found

Tags: c++, cmake, cgal

I want to use CGAL framework, so I tried to use CMAKE to build CGAL library,
but when I choose Visual Studio 2015 compiler, it shows the following error:

[image: CMake error description]

the error log contains:

> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.

Answer (score 0):

Last time far far away [someone else had the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31619842/7735711) as it appears to be even if you install Microsoft Visual Studio IDE, might've missed the option of installing the build tools.

As the previous answer states, try to create a new C++ project and as the Visual Studio prompts for installing missing components, install them. Should work again.

There's also [this solution that may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34736261/7735711). Best of luck.