# rc.exe no longer found in VS 2015 Command Prompt

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I just installed Windows 10 Creators Update (version 10.0.15063).

I have multiple versions of Visual Studio installed (2012, 2013, 2015 and 2017). I installed VS 2017 only a couple weeks ago.

#### Problem

CMake (version 3.8.1) no longer finds the C/C++ compiler when run inside a "VS2015 x64 Native Command Prompt" (it *does* work properly when run inside a VS 2017 command prompt).

#### Reproduction

Content of `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project (test)
add_executable (test test.cpp)
```

(Content of `test.cpp` is irrelevant.)

CMake invocation, in a VS2015 x64 Native Command Prompt:

```
> mkdir build
> cd build
> cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ..
```

CMake output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/dev/cmaketest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/dev/cmaketest/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

#### Analysis

The reason of the failure is clear when looking at `CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log`:

```
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc140.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue CMakeCCompilerId.c
  CMakeCCompilerId.c
Link:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:".\CompilerIdC.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB:".\CompilerIdC.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:".\CompilerIdC.lib" /MACHINE:X64 Debug\CMakeCCompilerId.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe' [D:\dev\cmaketest\build\CMakeFiles\3.8.1\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]
```

`rc.exe` (Resource Compiler) is not found. Indeed, in the same VS 2015 command prompt:

```
> where rc.exe
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

While it *is* found in a VS 2013 command prompt:

```
> where rc.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\rc.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\rc.exe
```

and a VS 2017 command prompt:

```
> where rc.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x64\rc.exe
```

Checking the content of the `PATH` environment variables in various VS command prompts:

- Inside a VS 2013 command prompt, `PATH` contains

  ```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64
  ```
- Inside a VS 2017 command prompt, `PATH` contains

  ```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x64
  ```
- But inside a VS 2015 command prompt, `PATH` only contains

  ```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64
  ```

  which does not contain `rc.exe`.

#### Questions

1. Is this a known issue or is it specific to my system?
2. What could Windows 10 Creators Update possibly install, uninstall or alter in the system (perhaps something related to Windows SDKs) that would trigger this problem?
3. What is a clean way to resolve this?

Edit: Installed VS 2017 components:

[image: VS 2017 components installed]

Comment: I have just hit the same problem with almost identical OS and Visual Studio setup as you.  

I am trying to build Wireshark (64-bit).bl  Strange thing is I have built it on two machines at home without hitting this problem. Now trying to build on my work machine and I hit the problem.  

I manually added  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x64  
  
to the PATH, but this then led to 'winver.h' not being found.

Comment: What update level of VS2015 are you using? On my home machine, which is running VS2015 Update 3, rc.exe is on the path in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\rc.EXE`.

Comment: @DaveCleland I'm running Visual Studio Entreprise 2015 Version 14.0.25425.01 Update 3.

Comment: FIVE HUNDRED BOUNTY

Comment: One fundamental pathway to exhibit this problem:  (1) buy a new clean Windows10 machine (late 2018).  (2) Install VS2017.   (3) Change your mind, uninstall (somehow or other) VS2017 and install VS2015.   ***This seems to fundamentally cause the 'windows cmake crisis' to exhibit.***

Comment: I found another solution that works with VS2015 and any Windows 10 SDK, doesn't involve putting copies of some indeterminate RC.EXE into the path or even updating the path, nor must VS2015 be started from a Visual Studio command prompt. I wrote it up on a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69684610/158024.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Spent some time looking at this on three machines with Win10 Creators Edition and VS2010, VS2013, VS2015 and VS2017 installed, where it works on two machines and fails on the third. All had VS2015 Update 3 and all should have been installed with the same options.

Running the following batch file

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat
```

should setup the correct environment for VS2015 x64 environment. This should add

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64
```

to the PATH. This is where **rc.exe**  should be. However on my failing machine **rc.exe** was missing from here, but it did exist in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x64
```

I went back and feeling like this was a setup issue I re-ran the VS2015 Update 3 setup and told it to add

**Windows and Web Development -> Universal Windows App Development Tools -> Tools (1.4.1) and Windows 10 SDK (10.0.14393)**

this caused **rc.exe** and related files to appear in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64
```

Running **rc -v** on

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x64\rc.exe
```

and

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\rc.exe
```

gave the same version number **10.0.10011.16384**

Not sure why rc.exe was missing from the original install, but re-running the install and adding the other SDK fixed it for me. It looks like

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\rc.exe
```

should be the default **rc.exe** but it was not setup by a previous install.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detailed investigation. A lot of people suffer from this problem, yet as far as I can tell no clean solution was offered anywhere until. Yours is the first clean solution. Thanks!

Comment: Works, just had add the path to the /bin with rc.exe in the PATH variables for it to work

Comment: Although vcvars64 (or `vcvarsall x64` under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC) adds the desired path and the reinstallation puts the exe into that path, all these works only for developer's command line; the VS2015 IDE still cannot find rc.exe and spit out the same error. So we might just as well add the path pointing to the rc.exe, no matter where it is, into the PATH environment variable, and we are all set. But I still wanna thank this answer 'cause at least it lets me know where rc.exe is.

Comment: thanks a billion for this @DaveCleland.  One detail, for now anyway (late 2018) it seems to offer you three version of the SDK to install.  **I stuck with exactly and only 10.0.10011.16384** and it **seems that is the only way to get this to work**.

Comment: I found another solution that works with any Windows 10 SDK, doesn't involve putting copies of some indeterminate RC.EXE into the path. I wrote it up on a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69684610/158024.

Comment: Installing 5Gb of extra to get one exe; <3 MS

Answer (score 20):

It's definitely not just you. I installed VS2017 yesterday and doing so seems to have produced the same problem on my end. I don't have a good solution (this should be reported to Microsoft as a bug) but I do have a hacky workaround.

I was able to copy rc.exe and rc.dll from

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x64 
to
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86
```

That resolved the issue for me. My hunch is that it's a registry key being overwritten but I haven't dug into it enough to be sure.

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure you meant `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86`, and not `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64`?

Comment: Oddly, on my machine, yes. It seemed odd, but my bin\x64 doesn't contain rc.exe or rc.dll. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks. @FrançoisBeaune copying the files into x64 did nothing for me, but x86 worked great.

Comment: It is called rcdll.dll on my machine. I also needed to copy mt.exe. Nevertheless, it worked (copying x86->x86 and x64->x64)

Answer (score 8):

Met the same problem with Windows 10 15063.608 (Windows SDK 10.0.15063.0). The solution working for me is the hard links creation for  Windows 10 kit binaries x64 and x86 folders like shown below (use the command prompt with admin rights):

```
mklink /J "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x86"

mklink /J "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x64"
```

(prior to running these commands just rename existing `Windows Kits\10\bin\x64` and `Windows Kits\10\bin\x86` folders - it looks like they are not in use.

P.S. `mklink` is a `CMD` command, not available under `PowerShell`

Answer (score 4):

For whatever reason the built-in **Tools (1.4.1) and Windows 10 SDK (10.0.14393)** installer didn't work for me:

1. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86` got populated mid-install (success!)
2. ...then de-populated (sorrow!)
3. And eventually the installer returned error `-2147023293`/`0x80048646`.

The ["Windows 10 SDK (ver. 10.0.14393.795)" installer](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=838916) from the [Windows SDK and emulator archive](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive) worked though: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86` gets and stays populated, including `rc.exe`.

Windows 7 x64, Visual Studio Professional 2015 Update 3.

Answer (score 2):

Specifying `CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=8.1` solved the problem for me.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix it in our case.

Answer (score 2):

Similar problem with VS2017 Community 15.4.5 with Windows Sdk version 10.0.16299.0, but only for builds via TeamCity; builds from within VS work fine and so does building with MSBuild when starting from a VS developer command prompt. So this does not exactly answer the OP's question, but is so similar and this is one of the first search matches so I'll add it here.

Found a solution which does *not* require modifying the installation in any way (no linking/copying so less error-prone and easy to automate):

set the `VisualStudioVersion` environment variable to `15.0`.

You could do this globally using the standard Windows gui for that (example for windows 10 [here](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)) but I'd rather strongly advise against it becaus it could interfere with other versions of VS, moreover it is not a change which is easily automated nor checked in into your build code and hence harder to reproduce omn different machines. A better alternative is to set this in the commandline where the build runs (cmd: `set VisualStudioVersion=15.0` PS: `$env:VisualStudioVersion = '15.0'` in TeamCity: add `env.VisualStudioVersion` Parameter). Another alternative is to pass this directory to MSBuild as a property (pass `/p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0` or in teamCity add `system.VisualStudioVersion`).

Comment: and how do you change that variable? any instructions?

Answer (score 2):

1. run your online installer vs_community2017.exe.
2. select modify your VS2017
3. select desktop development with C++
4. select Windows 10 SDK(my version is 10.0.10586) and install it

Run VS2015 command prompt:

```
> where rc
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\rc.exe
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\rc.exe
```

It seems that vs2017 default installs the newest SDK, and Overwrite old versions.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who gets stuck on this, one particular problem set is:

1. get a new **windows 10 PC**
2. install VS **2017** [*]
3. **uninstall** VS 2017 and
4. install VS **2015**

If you do the above,

it seems that there is a bug or other behavior with the overall suite of Windows/VS installers.

There are basically it seems four problems MSFT have to fix (a) sometimes it just doesn't install rc.exe, (b) it doesn't install rc.exe if you "only" ask for the c++ stuff, you must ask for everything (c) the uninstall-install pipeline seems to be all messed up in various ways (d) even if it randomly installs rc.exe for you, it forgets or fouls-up the path.

:/

Long tedious story short, solutions seem to include **one or more** of

1. basically install or re-install 10.0.10011.16384 **(but only that one, NOT the two later ones)**
2. look around and see if rc.exe is plain, outright, **not there**. If so, install it (somewhere, anywhere)
3. in VS, you'd think you can install "just" the c++ stuff, **but no**. In practice you MUST check yes to all the web, blah blah development stuff. This seems to give you "more hope" of getting rc.exe.  After doing this, revisit point 2, as you may well still not have it.
4. After doing 2 then 3 and likely 2 again, you likely STILL will not have it in your actual path. I would love to know which is the "best, natural" place to have it in your path, but that seems to be a lost cause. Just shove it in your path somewhere, anywhere.
5. **Create a simple cmake file somewhere - and test it works.**

. . . . . .

[*] it may well come with VS 2017, and don't forget VS 2017 may annoyingly get installed with something else, Unity etc.

Answer (score 1):

Open "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" in a text editor in administrator mode and change
the line

`@if not "%WindowsSdkDir%" == "" @set PATH=%WindowsSdkDir%bin\x86;%PATH%`

to

`@if not "%WindowsSdkDir%" == "" @set PATH=%WindowsSdkDir%bin\x86;%WindowsSdkDir%bin\%WindowsSDKVersion%x86;%PATH%`

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Multiple Visual studio versions, including 2015 and 2017.
My solution was to run the cmake command from 2017 developer command prompt, and specify the 2015 visual studio version with:

cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" ..

Answer (score 1):

Seems like when you install a newer version of Visual Studio the more recent SDK will be chosen by default.

You must select the SDK (8.1) that is installed with VS2015:

```
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" <arch> 8.1
```

I found the right answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46166632/1982767)

Answer (score 0):

execute following command on native 64/86 visual studio command prompt to set correct version For vs2015  -- 
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64 8.1
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 8.1

execute following command on native 64/86 visual studio command promptto set correct version For vs2013  - 
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64 7.1
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 7.1

This will set correct path and execute without any issue. 
I have tested this on WIN10 with VS2013,VS2015,VS2017 installed.

Answer (score 0):

After trying  to install > py -3.11 -m pip zodb I got that pesky LNK1158 error.

I have VC files at:

Host Target Resource Compiler Version 10.0.10011.16384

x64  x64    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\rc.exe"

x64  x64    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\rcdll.dll"

x64  x86    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86\rc.exe"

x64  x86    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86\rcdll.dll"

Host Target Linker Version 14.00.24245.0

x64  x64    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\link.exe"

x86  x86    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\link.exe"

x64  x86    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64_x86\link.exe"

x86  x64    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe"

LINK need RC for cPersist from persistent-4.9.1.tar.gz

Setup.py run x86_amd64 tools for target Python 3.11.0rc2 64-bit

=> need to copy x64-x64 rc.exe and rcdll.dll to x86_amd64 directory

Because I'm lazy - fast XCOPY was enough and then new try:

PS > py -3.11 -m pip install zodb

... later ...

PS > # NO ERRORS - I AM HAPPY GUY NOW!