# Problem in Building openssl_1.0.2p in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, openssl

Am building new release of openssl_1.0.2p using Visual Studio 2015 Command Prompts. I have installed perl and sed. I have written some batch files to build x86 and x64 libraries. When I built same openssl version in VS 2013 and VS 2017 am not facing any issue.

But while building in VS 2015 am unable to build. When I build x86 library in “VS2015 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt” then  its building fine and resulting in generating include and lib folder. But when I try to build DLL library then am getting fatal error which says

rc /fo"tmp32dll\libeay32.res" /d CRYPTO ms\version32.rc

‘rc’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.

NMAKE : fatal error V1077: ‘rc’ : return code ‘0x1’
Stop.
        1 dir(s) moved.
        1 dir(s) moved.”

I have attached screenshot too.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV6yz.png)

Comment: The problem description for this question (which has an accepted answer) looks very similar: [rc.exe no longer found in VS 2015 Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43847542/rc-exe-no-longer-found-in-vs-2015-command-prompt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is Solved. Windows and Web Development package was not installed in VS 2015. I installed it and now openssl is building fine.

If anyone wants to install these packages then goto control panel-> programs and features -> VS 2015
Right Click on VS 2015 -> change -> Modify -> select Windows and Web Development - > install