# Error while building C++ Protobuf using cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, protobuf-3

Following the steps in the README.file for protobuf version 3.17 C++ and after creating release folder and running

```
C:\Path\to\protobuf\cmake\build\release>cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ^
     -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ^
     -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../../../../install ^
     ../..,
```

getting the following error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/reeba/Documents/protobuf/cmake/build/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):nmake -f Makefile /nologo cmTC_c3bac\fast &&   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\nmake.exe"  -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_c3bac.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_c3bac.dir\build
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_c3bac.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_cl_compile_depends --dep-file=CMakeFiles\cmTC_c3bac.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj.d --working-dir=C:\Users\reeba\Documents\protobuf\cmake\build\release\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp --filter-prefix="Note: including file: " -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\ENTERP~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1429~1.301\bin\Hostx86\x64\cl.exe @C:\Users\reeba\AppData\Local\Temp\nm535C.tmp
    testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_c3bac.exe
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_c3bac.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\ENTERP~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1429~1.301\bin\Hostx86\x64\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_c3bac.dir\objects1.rsp @C:\Users\reeba\AppData\Local\Temp\nm53CA.tmp
    RC Pass 1: command "rc /fo CMakeFiles\cmTC_c3bac.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_c3bac.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
    The system cannot find the file specifiedNMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"' : return code '0xffffffff'
    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.
```

Using VS2019 and cmake  3.20.
Can anyone help with this?

Comment: is `rc` available on your path? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43847542/rc-exe-no-longer-found-in-vs-2015-command-prompt

Comment: @AlanBirtles: yes it is