due to non-UTF-8 characters in the output during command execution, leading to decoding errors
1.I am building tmiv18.0 using the prebuild script provided by that project
https://gitlab.com/mpeg-i-visual/tmiv/-/blob/v18.0/doc/building.md
2.when I run
python I:\qyq\Encoder18\Workspace\tmiv\scripts\build\build_dependencies.py \
-i I:\qyq\Encoder18\Workspace\tmiv_install

the cmd outputs
 cmake -G Ninja -S I:/qyq/Encoder18/Workspace/tmiv/.deps/build/RelWithDebInfo-2a4bfb3604278518c9c69240a3222993/HM-src -B I:/qyq/Encoder18/Workspace/tmiv/.deps/build/RelWithDebInfo-2a4bfb3604278518c9c69240a3222993/HM-HM-16.16 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=I:/qyq/Encoder18/Workspace/tmiv_install -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=14
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.39.33523.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.39.33523.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at I:/qyq/Encoder18/Workspace/tmiv/.venv/Lib/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:70 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: I:/qyq/Encoder18/Workspace/tmiv/.deps/build/RelWithDebInfo-2a4bfb3604278518c9c69240a3222993/HM-HM-16.16/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-g9oe0y

    Run Build Command(s):I:/qyq/Encoder18/Workspace/tmiv/.venv/Scripts/ninja.exe cmTC_2eab2 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_2eab2.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj
    [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_2eab2.exe
    FAILED: cmTC_2eab2.exe
    cmd.exe /C "cd . && I:\qyq\Encoder18\Workspace\tmiv\.venv\Lib\site-packages\cmake\data\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_2eab2.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1439~1.335\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_2eab2.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmTC_2eab2.exe /implib:cmTC_2eab2.lib /pdb:cmTC_2eab2.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
    RC Pass 1: command "rc /fo CMakeFiles\cmTC_2eab2.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_2eab2.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\qyq\Encoder18\Workspace\tmiv\scripts\build\build_dependencies.py", line 201, in <module>
    main()
  File "I:\qyq\Encoder18\Workspace\tmiv\scripts\build\build_dependencies.py", line 24, in main
    build_dependency(d, args)
  File "I:\qyq\Encoder18\Workspace\tmiv\scripts\build\build_dependencies.py", line 105, in build_dependency
    cmake_configure(source_dir, build_dir, install_dir, args.build_type, dep["variables"])
  File "I:\qyq\Encoder18\Workspace\tmiv\scripts\build\build_dependencies.py", line 147, in cmake_configure
    run(args)
  File "I:\qyq\Encoder18\Workspace\tmiv\scripts\build\build_dependencies.py", line 158, in run
    for line in process.stdout:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 36: illegal multibyte sequence

3.The runtime environment of the code：
windows10
visual studio 2022
python 3.10
cmd
1.I have tried match the version of windows SDK and visual studio.
2.I have configured the environment variables for Visual Studio.
3.I have checked the "build_dependencies.py" file and the encoding format has been set to UTF-8.

Comment out the for loop that raises the exception. Seems the lines are just printing stdout.

I'd guess you're missing rc.exe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43847542/rc-exe-no-longer-found-in-vs-2015-command-prompt
