# Can't install mod_wsgi on wamp64 apache2.4.23 python35 (32 bit). error status 1120 link.exe

Tags: mod-wsgi

getting this when running : `pip install -v mod_wsgi` (just copying the error part since the whole thing is too big) what is the meaning of single version externally managed

> pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command
>   "C:\Python\Python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-mwb58gi9\mod-wsgi\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-a_8yhdqk-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-mwb58gi9\mod-wsgi\

Comment: Have you installed the Microsoft C compiler corresponding to that Python version? https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: pleasantly surprised and appreciate fast response. I have installed visual C++ build tools 14 from Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 package since I was earlier getting an error requesting for this version.

Comment: Surprisingly, this solution worked for me. Can't believe it was as simple as this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/24984859/7247038    copied the file rc.exe and rcdll.dll from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64 to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin. Also upgraded the python version to 64 bit one