# Qt 5.8 msvc 2015 compile error

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I have installed Qt using an offline installer `qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2015_64-5.8.0`. I have visual studio community edition 2017 installed with c++ build tools. because it's compiler was incompatible with the qt version, then I installed **visual c++ build tools 2015** from http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools . When I try to compile a project it gives an error `:-1: error: LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'`. Heres how my qt kit looks like,
[image]

[image]

Can someone figure out whats the mistake and how to fix it. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you update to Qt 5.9 it supports MSVC 2017.  However, if you want to get it working with 5.8, I believe you might be missing the Windows SDK.  You can download the SDK from Microsoft for Windows 7, 8 or 10, just get whichever version is appropriate for you.

With some googling I found a couple of other somewhat related solutions [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/78214/trouble-with-msvc2015), & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372706/visual-studio-cant-build-due-to-rc-exe), and I've summed them up below:

If you've already got the SDK or installed it and it still doesn't work, it appears that copying rc.exe and rcdll.dll from the WindowsSDK folder to your MSVS installs \VC\bin folder may fix the problem.  You might also try copying those same two files to Qt's \Qt*version number**compiler version*\bin.

Comment: Thanks so much for that solution! I just had to google the right thing to find it. Solved my problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

I've fixed this both on my own machine and on several co-workers machines.

It tends to happen when you have both Visual Studio 2015 and VS 2017 installed. Or more precisely, multiple versions of the Windows SDK installed.  When that happens, the `vcvars32.bat` script (located in your Visual Studio install dir) does not correctly add the location of the resource compiler (rc.exe) to your PATH. Thus, QT Creator runs vcvars32.bat (as specified in Qt Creator under Option->Build&Run->Compilers, but the tools directory for the Windows SDK Kit isn't properly added to the PATH environment.

The simple fix is to add the appropriate version of RC.exe to your path.

Do this from the command line:

```
cd "c:\program files(x86)"
dir /s rc.exe
```

You'll get several versions (x86 and x64) and for several versions of the SDK.  Add the PATH for where rc.exe lives for the version that corresponds to the SDK and build flavor to your vcvars32.bat startup script.

For example:

```
PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x86";%PATH%
```

Restart Qt Creator and that should fix it.

Another fix that worked for me is to uninstall all versions of Visual Studio (and all those side installs of SQL, Windows SDKs, dev tools, etc...). Reboot. Then cleanly install VS 2017 again.  Then cleanly uninstall and re-install all of Qt again. That seemed to work for me. A wonderful way to spend an afternoon.

Comment: Thanks. This clearly explained what the issue was. The issue is in msvc and not qt. Anyway these kind of faults are very hard to figure out alone. Thanks again sir.

Comment: Thanks! Install of a new Windows 10 SDK broke my Qt 5.9.6 MSVC 2015 32-bit IDE debugging and resource compiling.  All is good now!