# Issues in install annoy python package

Tags: python, pip, conda

Unable to install annoy package for Python 3.6 on Windows 10.

Both of the commands:

```
pip install annoy
conda install python-annoy      // fails even after adding conda-forge channel
```

fail.

Error :
    fatal error LNK1158: cannot run ‘rc.exe’

Comment: What is the error message? Share traceback.

Comment: since it internally uses c++ libraries,there can be the issue with your c++ environment.

Answer (score 0):

The error got fixed by setting PATH

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64
```

and running

```
vcvarsall.bat
```

as mentioned in the post:
[Visual Studio can't build due to rc.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372706/visual-studio-cant-build-due-to-rc-exe)