# My newest Windows 10 SDK installation does not include rc.exe and rcdll.exe so I get LNK1158 error

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sdk

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, On Windows 10 Professional. I just installed the latest version of Windows SDK. I'm trying to compile a VC++ Console Application, very simple, but I cannot compile it because I get this error:

```
LINK: fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'
```

I tried googling and I came up with [this QandA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372706/visual-studio-cant-build-due-to-rc-exe) but I can't find any rc.exe and rcdll.exe in my /kits/10/bin folder! Where could the problem lie?

If it matters, I installed the SDK version that came with the setup, and then installed the newest Windows 10 SDK that was on this ISO file:

```
17763.1.180914-1434.rs5_release_WindowsSDK.iso
```

Comment: Starting with the Windows 8 SDK, compilers are no longer part of the installation. You need to use the tools that come with the IDE. Do you get the error when building from within the IDE, or are you using the command prompt? In the latter case make sure to use one of the Developer Command Prompts installed with the IDE. If you open it, run `where rc` to see whether it is properly configured.

Comment: @IInspectable Could you elaborate, please? What its a Developer Command Prompt? I'm compiling within the IDE. My code has no issues, I've compiled it with Clion+MinGWx64.

Comment: A Developer Command Prompt is a pre-configured command prompt. The Visual Studio installer places shortcuts to several configurations in the Start Menu.

Comment: @IInspectable Could you please upload the files I need somewhere and give them to me? I completely trust you. I fail to see any other way, as Visual Studio has no created any shortcuts in my Start Menu. Plus, I have browsed the folders and I didn't see any rc.exe or rcdll.dll. I think this is the only way.

Comment: Sounds like a failed/broken installation. Try to repair the Visual Studio installation or reinstall it if that fails.

Comment: Having the same issue with SDK 10.0.18362 installed using the Visual Studio Installer

Answer (score 2):

I have read that rc.exe is no longer included in the Windows SDK. I had installed the oldest MSVC C++ compiler in the Visual Studio 2019 installer, but it did not contain rc.exe either. I installed the newest (which is also version 14, but with a higher minor version number!) and it contains rc.exe.

Comment: Look in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x86

Comment: Do you know the version ?

Comment: @eri0o Do I know the version of what?

Comment: The version of the package/install that came with the `rc.exe`. I am trying to setup a windows container but msbuild can't find `rc.exe`.