# Visual Studio 2019: build C++ from command line with vcvars64.bat doesn't work anymore

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In order to compile an app with cl cpp compiler in the command line on previous versions of Visual studio I ran the vcvars64.bat script and then compiler worked as expected.

I have recently installed Visual Studio 2019. I have found vcvar64.bat script at the following location: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build`.

But running this script doesn't make cl compiler work. Even simple 3 line cpp files fail compilation with silly errors like "stddef.h" file not found. Compiler works as expected if you are using it from IDE.

What do you need to do to make VS2019 cpp compiler work in command line?

Comment: Try `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64` (sorry about formatting, took it from a script I use)

Comment: @ChrisMM vcvars64.bat just calls `vcvarsall.bat" x64` so should be equivalent

Comment: @AlanBirtles, ah yes, you're right. Didn't look at what the `.bat` files did. My script uses `vcvarsall.bat` directly

Comment: A few things to try:  You could run one of the Command Prompt links from the start menu.  You could check the INCLUDE environment variable in your command prompt after running vcvars64.bat.  Check your install of VS to verify that you've installed the proper parts of the C++ tools.

Comment: Any news here? Got the same errors. `vcvarsall.bat` and the Developer Prompts won't detect the windows kits. When trying to add the includes it works until the linker searches for libraries to link, for example `ole32.lib`. The linker can't find them. Seems like the scripts are buggy and/or the installer changed somehow.

Answer (score 4):

In my visual studio 2019 installation `stddef.h` is found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt`. `vcvars.bat` should be adding this path to the `INCLUDE` environment variable.

Running the following might provide some hints:

```
set VSCMD_DEBUG=3
vcvars64.bat > out.txt
```

In my installation searching out.txt for `call :GetWin10SdkDir` comes to the section where the bat file is searching for a SDK directory. Hopefully there will be some error messages in there somewhere.

For reference these are the additional environment variables set by a working call to vcvars64.bat on my machine:

```
CommandPromptType=Native
DevEnvDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\
ExtensionSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs
Framework40Version=v4.0
FrameworkDir=C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\
FrameworkDIR64=C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64
FrameworkVersion=v4.0.30319
FrameworkVersion64=v4.0.30319
HTMLHelpDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop
INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt
LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x64;
LIBPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\lib\x86\store\references;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17763.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17763.0;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;
NETFXSDKDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX64\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VS15Preview\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VS15Preview\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\\MSBuild\Current\Bin;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\;
Platform=x64
UCRTVersion=10.0.17763.0
UniversalCRTSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
VCIDEInstallDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\
VCINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\
VCToolsInstallDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\
VCToolsRedistDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.24.28127\
VCToolsVersion=14.24.28314
VisualStudioVersion=16.0
VS160COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\
VSCMD_ARG_app_plat=Desktop
VSCMD_ARG_HOST_ARCH=x64
VSCMD_ARG_TGT_ARCH=x64
VSCMD_VER=16.4.2
VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\
WindowsLibPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17763.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17763.0
WindowsSdkBinPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\
WindowsSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
WindowsSDKLibVersion=10.0.17763.0\
WindowsSdkVerBinPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\
WindowsSDKVersion=10.0.17763.0\
WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\
WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\
__DOTNET_ADD_64BIT=1
__DOTNET_PREFERRED_BITNESS=64
```

If all else fails a re-install of visual studio is likely to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all ,you should install either Visual Studio and the optional Desktop development with C++ workload, or the command-line Build Tools for Visual Studio.

> Before you can build a C or C++ program on the command line, you must
>   verify that the tools are installed, and that you can access them from
>   the command line. Visual C++ has complex requirements for the
>   command-line environment to find the tools, headers, and libraries it
>   uses. You can't use Visual C++ in a plain command prompt window
>   without doing some preparation. Fortunately, Visual C++ installs
>   shortcuts for you to launch a developer command prompt that has the
>   environment set up for command line builds. Unfortunately, the names
>   of the developer command prompt shortcuts and where they're located
>   are different in almost every version of Visual C++ and on different
>   versions of Windows.
>
> A developer command prompt shortcut automatically sets the correct
>   paths for the compiler and tools, and for any required headers and
>   libraries. You must set these environment values yourself if you use a
>   regular Command Prompt window.

If you get an error such as "'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file," error C1034, or error LNK1104 when you run the cl command, then either you are not using a developer command prompt, or something is wrong with your installation of Visual C++.

I suggest you could try to use `Developer Command Prompt for VS` directly. Please open the Start menu and choose All apps. Scroll down and open the Visual Studio folder (not the Visual Studio application). Choose Developer Command Prompt for VS to open the command prompt window.

For more details I suggest you could refer to the DOC:[Walkthrough: Compiling a Native C++ Program on the Command Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compiling-a-native-cpp-program-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019)

Comment: don't think any of this advice is relevant. He states he's getting include errors so `cl` must be running. Running `Developer Command Prompt for VS` is just a shortcut to `vcvarsall.bat`.