# RC error at configure time with MSVC2019 and Ninja

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake, ninja

I'm trying to use Ninja to improve my build times with a Visual Studio 2019 project that we already successfully build with CMake.

Now I'm trying a simple

```
cmake . -GNinja
```

but it is getting an error at compile time trying to detect the compiler.

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30147.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:62 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/build-ninja/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/ninja.exe cmTC_2be2a && [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\cmTC_2be2a.dir\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj
    [2/2] Linking CXX executable cmTC_2be2a.exe
    FAILED: cmTC_2be2a.exe
    cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_2be2a.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1429~1.301\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_2be2a.dir\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj  /out:cmTC_2be2a.exe /implib:cmTC_2be2a.lib /pdb:cmTC_2be2a.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\build-ninja\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp && C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/msbuild/applocal.ps1 -targetBinary C:/build-ninja/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/cmTC_2be2a.exe -installedDir C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/bin -OutVariable out""
    RC Pass 1: command "rc /fo CMakeFiles\cmTC_2be2a.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_2be2a.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
    The system cannot find the file specified
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

It seems that some step with `rc` tool is failing. Any ideas here?

Comment: Are you running this from a Visual Studio 2019 x64 Native tools command prompt so that vcvarsall.bat was run and the environment variables for msvc are enabled?

Comment: IMHO, your dependencies are messed up.  If a file is not found, there should be rules on how to create the file (the meat of a makefile).  Verify your dependencies are correctly set up; `cmake` may have a command line to display the searching.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews this is a `try_compile` step automatically conducted by CMake when detecting the compiler. I doubt my project has anything to do with this

Comment: May help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57348542/cmake-will-not-be-able-to-correctly-generate-this-project-call-stack-most-rece](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57348542/cmake-will-not-be-able-to-correctly-generate-this-project-call-stack-most-rece)