# Getting issues Installing Regex via PIP

Tags: python, regex

Ongoing adventures trying to get GPT-2 working under W10

I've installed the relevant version of VC++ Build Tools, however, I'm now getting the following error.

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\ianholdsworth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\IANHOL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ti712svq\\regex\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\IANHOL~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ti712svq\\regex\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\IANHOL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-mhweepz9' --python-tag cp37
       cwd: C:\Users\IANHOL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ti712svq\regex\
  Complete output (26 lines):
  c:\users\ianholdsworth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:470: UserWarning: Normalizing '2017.04.05' to '2017.4.5'
    normalized_version,
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  copying Python3\regex.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  copying Python3\_regex_core.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  copying Python3\test_regex.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  running build_ext
  building '_regex' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\Python3
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\ianholdsworth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\ianholdsworth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" /TcPython3\_regex.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\Python3\_regex.obj
  _regex.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\ianholdsworth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\ianholdsworth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" /TcPython3\_regex_unicode.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\Python3\_regex_unicode.obj
  _regex_unicode.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\ianholdsworth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\ianholdsworth\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit__regex build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\Python3\_regex.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\Python3\_regex_unicode.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\_regex.cp37-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\Python3\_regex.cp37-win_amd64.lib
  _regex.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit__regex' specified multiple times; using first specification
     Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\Python3\_regex.cp37-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\Python3\_regex.cp37-win_amd64.exp
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for regex
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/14372706/11301900.

Answer (score -1):

[Visual Studio can't build due to rc.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372706/visual-studio-cant-build-due-to-rc-exe?newreg=f00ac10c2a4448ceb438f258e5c229a4)

To fix the issue, do next steps:

Add this to your PATH environment variables:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64
```

Copy these files rc.exe & rcdll.dll from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86` 
to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin`

In newer Windows these files might also be in the highest version: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.VERSION\x86`